# NodeJS problem with recurring events from ICal

Tags: javascript, node.js, icalendar

I'm using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ical node module to parse an ICal file to a JavaScript object. So now I want to have a function that gives me all events for the current week. My problem is, that there are recurring events. I've not found a property that helps me to identify when the recurring range starts and ends. 
How to process this ICal recurring events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [rrule package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rrule), you can create recurring events with it:

```js
const rule = new RRule({
  freq: RRule.WEEKLY,
  interval: 5,
  byweekday: [RRule.MO, RRule.FR],
  dtstart: new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 1, 1, 10, 30)),
  until: new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 12, 31))
})
```

or even parse a recurrence rule string:

```js
rrulestr('DTSTART:20120201T023000Z\nRRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;COUNT=5')
```

It has many other helper functions too such as between, before, all, etc.